# Force application to run only in one instance in PCF

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I have one scheduler app to be run only in one instance in PCF cloud environment. Is there any way to do it in Cloud environment ?

Few of the things I tried by making instances:1 in manifest.yml , to force it to run only in one instance and not autoscale .

But looking for any better approach in PCF .

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen done here is to have your app look at the environment variable `CF_INSTANCE_INDEX`. This is the zero based index which shows the instance number of your application. So 0 is the first instance, 1 is the second, 2 is the third, etc...

Have your app look at this env variable and if the value isn't 0, then have it exit or do nothing or whatever makes sense. By doing this, only your first app instance will cause this bit of code to run. The rest will skip or not do anything.

The other option, which is a little newer, is to use multiple processes within your app. This would allow you to have a web process and a separate worker/scheduler process (whatever you want to call it). You can then scale them independently, so your web process can go as high as needed but your other process could be set to one.

You achieve this by making a `Procfile` with something like this:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake worker:start
```

And using `cf7 push myapp` or `cf v3-push myapp`.

Full instructions are here:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/multiple-processes.html

I will repeat that this is newer and if you're using some autoscaling technology, you'd want to make sure it's compatible with this new method of deploying apps.

Answer (score 1):

This will support cf v7.
Or you might be able to schedule it with the cf task option.

And as shown above, you can create various tasks through cf7.

https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.81.0/index.html#the-process-object

This can be separated into several processes as shown below.

```
applications:
name: cf-env
  buildpacks:
  ruby_buildpack
  processes:
  type: web
    instances: 1
    memory: 256M
  routes:
  route: all-new-route.cfapps.io
```